# Prolog check for predicate category

Tags: prolog

I have been working with Prolog since today, and wanted to create a simple test case. The basic idea was to have multiple sports defined, and it looks as follows:

```
soccer :- category(ball_sport),
    check(has_11_players_per_team),
    check(large_ball),
    check(use_feet).
tennis :- category(ball_sport),
    ...

category(ball_sport) :- 
    check(has_a_ball).
```

Now I wanted to create a testcase, to see if both sports are of the ball_sport category, but have no idea to check these sports against eachother .. I thought it would be something like the code below, but it's obvious not. Is there an easy way to check these predicate categories? Thanks

```
 both_ballsports(sport_one, sport_two) :-
        has_category(sport_one, ball_sport),
        has_category_sport_two, ball_sport).
```

Comment: What are you using as your learning source? A book? A website?

Comment: @GuyCoder It's from school, which posted only the following link to create our own https://gist.github.com/adrianomelo/207c4da2f50744f04c9d The idea is to base it on this and create test cases for our own predicates (note that it is only an into to prolog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that first of all, you want to declaratively state **attributes** of a sport.

For example:

```
sport_attributes(soccer, [ball_sport,players(22),ball(large),use(feet)]).
sport_attributes(tennis, [ball_sport,players(2),players(4),ball(small),use(racket)]).
```

Note that I am *relating* sports to attributes. For comparison, the goals of the form `check(X)` you use above all seem to **lack a critical argument**, namely the actual sport for which they hold (or not). For example, the goal `check(use_feet)` either holds *or not*, but there is no means to qualify a unary predicate of this kind and state different facts for different sports.

Note the naming convention: We describe what each argument means, separated by *underscores*.

With this representation, `both_ballsports/2` could look like this:

```
both_ballsports(Sport1, Sport2) :-
        ballsport(Sport1),
        ballsport(Sport2).

ballsport(Sport) :-
        sport_attributes(Sport, As),
        member(ball(_), As).
```

Sample query and answer:

```
?- both_ballsports(Sport1, Sport2).
Sport1 = Sport2, Sport2 = soccer ;
Sport1 = soccer,
Sport2 = tennis ;
Sport1 = tennis,
Sport2 = soccer ;
Sport1 = Sport2, Sport2 = tennis ;
false.
```

This can be used in **all directions**!

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for indeed, was hoping to check it direct, without defining all these attributes, since it seems kind of redundant (or I will check if they can be replaced), but thanks a lot, this does what it needs to do!